# How to add/connect NIB to programmatically created UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

First of all, I'm a beginner, so I might have my concepts wrong.

This is my code in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The idea is to programmatically add UINavigationController, but then use a .xib (the "FirstView" paremeter) for the views. I have no problem with programmatically creating the views as well, but for simpler interfaces, I assume using IB can be done as well.

However, when I run the code, I get this error:

```
2013-07-11 21:20:42.644 new-book-proto-01[64308:11303] *** Terminating app due
to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "FirstView" nib
but the view outlet was not set.'
```

What should I do? Is there anything missing?

Additionally, is something like this common in iOS development? Is it bad practice? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In FirstView.xib file, check whether view outlet has been set to FileOwner's view property or not?

Comment: @Mrunal is right it sounds like that's the problem here. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: @Mrunal How do I do that? I'm not quite familiar with XCode's UI yet.

Comment: Open you FirstView.xib 
Check if UIView is connected to your File's owner. 
If not, just drag from UIView with right mouse button to File's owner and connect to view property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason as told: "reason: 
'-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "FirstView" nib
but the view outlet was not set.' "

It means that you try to access or get value for some views (UI elements) that has not IBOutlet in your controller class or you have none view at all

You should create IBOutlets (properties) for each view (each UI element is view) that you would like to "see" in your controller

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So the problem is with the UI elements I have instead of their parent view? Also, do I create the IBOOutlets programmatically or via Xcode's UI?